# Why the websocket does not call the backend after the first use?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, websocket

I have the following JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/socket1")
    websocket.onmessage = function(erg){
        console.log("haha");
    }
    $("#start").click(function(){
        websocket.send("hi server")
    });
});
```

when I load the page and press the start button for first time the code call my backend but after that it does not call it. I should reload the page and click the start button again if I want second call. Why this is happening ?

It is possible the problem to be in my backend which is java spring boot. I use AbstractWebSocketHandler with WebSocketConfigurer and in my WebSocketHandler I use handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) method in order to get the request from the fronend.

Maybe I should handle the requests in different way ?

Comment: `websocket.onmessage` should be declared outside the click handler

Comment: ok but even outside it does not work again ..

Comment: i edited the code. This way its better. Thanks